# Firing an Event on <video> end with JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm firing an event when a video is completed using:

```
video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    //whatever
});
```

This works if I grab the selector via pure javascript: `var video = document.getElementById('test');`

This doesn't work if I grab the selector via jQuery: `var video = $("#test");`

Why is this the case? [Here's the accompanying JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/w4zahwk9/3/)

Comment: $("#test").on("ended", fn) doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because `$("#test")` returns a jQuery object. Use `$("#test").get(0)` to get the first dom element.

`var video = $("#test").get(0);`

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, use the `.on()` method:

```
jqueryVideo.on("ended", function() {
    console.log('This Works 2');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4zahwk9/4/

Comment: Both answers technically work, I choose the other one as the answer because it actually explained why "var video = $("#test");" didn't work.

Comment: This is the right approch. The selector .get(0) is doing exactly what native dom does. So you are unnecsarrly putting extra overhead of jquery for the call and calling .get(0).